# IDW10201: Neither scope or roles claim was found in the bearer token. custom web api core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I have an app registration like this:

[image]

In my webappi my app settings.json: I have this:

```
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "xx.com.co",
    "TenantId": "xx-c220-48a2-a73f-1177fa2c098e",
    "ClientId": "xx-3737-48a5-a6c0-7e3bc4f9a5c9",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "Scopes" : "userimpersonation"

  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

In my Startup.cs:

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
```

And in my controller:

```
[Authorize]
    [RequiredScope(RequiredScopesConfigurationKey = "AzureAd:Scopes")]
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
    {
```

So, I run thhe web app, and I get a token via postman:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/xx-c220-48a2-a73f-1177fa2c098e/oauth2/v2.0/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--header 'Cookie: wlidperf=FR=L&ST=1526512036088; fpc=AnqPVmkUS_BIgf3y-QfBcFEzTZcDBQAAAKAv0dcOAAAA; stsservicecookie=ests; x-ms-gateway-slice=prod' \
--form 'grant_type="client_credentials"' \
--form 'client_secret="xx"' \
--form 'client_id="xx-3737-48a5-a6c0-7e3bc4f9a5c9
"' \
--form 'scope="api://xx-3737-48a5-a6c0-7e3bc4f9a5c9/.default
"'
```

That works fine, however if I channge the scope to: api://xx-3737-48a5-a6c0-7e3bc4f9a5c9/userimpersonation.

Then I get this error:

```
AADSTS70011: The provided request must include a 'scope' input parameter. The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid
```

If I use the token provided with the default scope, when I call my controller, I get the following error:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: IDW10201: Neither scope or roles claim was found in the bearer token. 
   at Microsoft.Identity.Web.MicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthenticationBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.<<AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiImplementation>b__1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.AuthenticateAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Comment: You need to add `approle`.

Comment: see:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/InpBW.png

Comment: is app role a parameter to get the token? I already added it in the app registration, but not sure how to use it

Comment: Go to client application>API permissions>Add a permission>My APIs>your api application

Comment: I will do it once it works and I understand it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create two applications, one as a client application and the other as a api application. Then you need to create the **appRole** of the api application, and then grant that role as an **application permission** to the client application.

[image]

Comment: that is not explained inn the documentation: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/wiki/web-apis

Comment: @LuisValencia I think the document you shared has mentioned app role for client credentials flow: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/wiki/web-apis#web-apis-called-by-daemon-apps-using-client-credential-flow. So Carl should be correct.

Comment: app role for client credentials flow is for daemon apps.

Comment: @LuisValencia You mean you don't want to use client credentials flow? But why you are using client credentials flow in Postman?

Comment: @LuisValencia App role is application permission in this case. But when you choose to **Expose an API**, it is delegated permission. I see you are using client credentials flow in Postman, so I thought you used the wrong permission type.

Comment: I will try to be clearer next:   Yes my web api will be consumed by an app developed in react.   However before I send the API to my front end developers, I want to test that authentication works locally.     If I create another app in Azure AD, then in postman I should use the app id of the  new app?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229439/discussion-between-luis-valencia-and-allen-wu).